# Node - download zip and extract sequentially

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm

I am working on a Node Express, which would call REST URL to download a zip and extract it.

Below are the steps that I am following

1. Using the request module, send a POST request to REST API.
2. REST API returns a zip file. Pipe it to save it to the filesystem
3. Extract the zip file
4. Cleanup the zip file (this code is not there yet)

This is how my code looks like

```
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  var req = require('request');
  var extract = require('extract-zip');
  var postData = {
    username: "abc",
    password: "zyz"
  }
  var options = {
    method: 'post',
    body: postData,
    json: true,
    url: "http://localhost:8080/zipdownload"
  }
  req(options, function(err, res, body) {
    if(err) {
      console.log('Error posting json ' + err)
      return;
    }
  }).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(USER_DIR + '/MY.zip')).on('finish', function() {
    console.log('Finished downloading ZIP file');
    extract(USER_DIR + '/MY.zip', {
      dir: USER_DIR + '/MyExtractedFolder'
    }, function(err) {
      if(err) {
        console.log('Error extracting  zip ' + err);
      }
      resolve("Promised resolved donwloading and extracting zip");
    })
  }).on('error', function(error) {
    reject('Error in downloading content', error);
  });
});
```

I am able to download the zip file and save it in the file system using .pipe. However when I try to extract it using extract-zip, it gives me the below error

> End of central directory record signature not found.

I suspect that extract code is not at the right place and Promise gets resolved while the extract code is still running. As a result, the calling function, tries to do something with the extracted files which do not currently exist.

Also, I am not able to make out where should I put the code for zip cleanup. It needs to trigger once the extraction has been done and not in parallel to extraction.

Comment: It looks like you are calling extract function on request finish, not on write stream close event.

Comment: My understanding was that it would be called on finish of createWriteStream pipe